# Add CSS circle - crop top half of circle

Tags: html, css

I have the following button on my site:
http://jsfiddle.net/32u5x5uf/

I'd first like to move the span circle to be exactly in the center of the main button. I'd then like if I can somehow "merge" the two shapes together in CSS. So basically remove the top half of the circle and the main bar that cuts through the middle of the circle.

```css
.full-circle {
 border: 2px solid #1588CB;
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 -moz-border-radius:30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 position:absolute;
bottom:-20px;
}

button {
background:#ffffff;
border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
border: 2px solid #1588CB;
color:#1588CB;
font-weight:400;
height:200px;
width:400px;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<button>Learn More
    <span class="full-circle">+</span>
</button>
```

Comment: can u please post an image of how the box should look?

Comment: Sorry, that's a great idea. Here we are: http://imgur.com/JQjmymJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```css
.full-circle {
 border: 2px solid #1588CB;
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
-moz-border-radius:30px;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-20px;
}

button {
background:#ffffff;
border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
border: 2px solid #1588CB;
color:#1588CB;
font-weight:400;
height:200px;
width:400px;
position:relative;
}

/* overides ... */
.full-circle {
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  border-top: none;
  height: 17px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17px;
  bottom: -19px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Learn More
    <span class="full-circle">+</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer above by [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/turnip) is actually kind of a cheat with same

`background-color`

If that's not the case then you should go with this:

```css
div {
    background-color: #80C5A0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50% / 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```